# Function composition in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f\in L^2(0,\infty)$ with $|f(x)| \leq |x|$. Further, define $g(x)=d^x$ for some $d>1$.

**Question:** Is $f\circ g \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

If yes, how do I show this? If no, under which conditions does this hold?

Intuitively, this should hold, but I have no clue if this can be shown based on the above conditions. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is to determine whether the integral 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\left\lvert  f\left(e^{x\ln b}\right)\right\rvert^2\mathrm dx.
$$
Since $\ln b\gt 0$, this reduces to determine finiteness of $$
\int_{\mathbb R}\left\lvert  f\left(e^{u}\right)\right\rvert^2\mathrm du
$$
by letting $u=x\ln b$. Now, letting $t=e^u$, we have to investigate the convergence of 
$$
\int_{(0,+\infty)}\frac 1t\left\lvert  f\left(t\right)\right\rvert^2\mathrm dt.
$$
On $(0,1)$, use the condition $\left\lvert  f\left(t\right)\right\rvert\leqslant t$ and on $(1,+\infty)$, use square integrability of $f$.

Comment: I'm curious, is the growth condition $|f(x)|\leq C |x|$ (for some $C>0$) a characterization of the composable functions in $L^2$ to itself?